# How to store, version and deploy elastic search river plugin settings?

Tags: jakarta-ee, elasticsearch

I am deploying ES [embedded](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-transport-wares) in a Java EE project and try to provide the configuration needed for setting up the whole application including the ES and ES plugin config within the war file. At the moment I am integrating the [jdbc river plugin](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/). There is plenty of documentation about how to configure (the) plugin(s) via the ES REST API and it works just fine but I don't find information about how to bundle configuration into a settings file which I can provide to ES to setup the rivers.

How can I create a self-contained version controlled package of ES?
Is there an ES way of doing this like with elasticsearch.yml for the core settings or would I need to update my ES settings manually / programmatically?

Note: The war embedded ES config is a requirement but feel free to answer how to archive this for a standalone ES config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record: I ended up writing a ElasticSearchStarter that configures ES:

```java
package com.abc.xyz.resources.search;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings;
import org.elasticsearch.node.Node;
import org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class ElasticSearchStarter {

  private static final String TRANSPORT_TCP_PORT = "transport.tcp.port";

  private static final String TAGLINE = "tagline";

  private static final String DISCOVERY_ZEN_PING_MULTICAST_ENABLED = "discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled";

  public static final String INDEX = "abc";

  @Inject
  Logger logger;

  // es settings
  private static final String HTTP_ENABLED = "http.enabled";
  private static final String PATH_DATA = "path.data";
  private static final String PATH_WORK = "path.work";
  private static final String PATH_LOGS = "path.logs";
  private static final String PATH_UNICAST_HOSTS = "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts";

  @Resource(lookup = "java:global/xyz/ELASTIC_SEARCH_PATH_DATA")
  private String pathData;

  @Resource(lookup = "java:global/xyz/ELASTIC_SEARCH_PATH_WORK")
  private String pathWork;

  @Resource(lookup = "java:global/xyz/ELASTIC_SEARCH_PATH_LOGS")
  private String pathLogs;

  @Resource(lookup = "java:global/xyz/ELASTIC_SEARCH_TRANSPORT_TCP_PORT")
  private String transportTcpPort;

  @Resource(lookup = "java:global/xyz/ELASTIC_SEARCH_UNICAST_HOSTS")
  private String unicastHosts;

  protected Node node;

  @PostConstruct
  void init() throws ElasticSearchStartUpException {
    ImmutableSettings.Builder settings = buildSettings();

    node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().settings(settings).node();

    getNode().start();
  }

  private ImmutableSettings.Builder buildSettings() throws ElasticSearchStartUpException {
    // ES settings
    ImmutableSettings.Builder settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder();
    InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("elasticsearch.yml");
    if (resourceAsStream != null) {
      settings.loadFromStream("elasticsearch.yml", resourceAsStream);
      logger.info("Settings loaded from elasticsearch.yml");
      try {
        resourceAsStream.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        String msg = "Error loading Settings loaded from elasticsearch.yml";
        logger.error(msg + e);
        throw new ElasticSearchStartUpException(msg, e);
      }
    } else {
      String msg = "Loading elasticsearch.yml failed! resourceAsStream was null";
      logger.error(msg );
      throw new ElasticSearchStartUpException(msg);
    }

    // See also elasticsearch.yml
    settings.put(TAGLINE, "You know nothing... Ask me!");
    settings.put(HTTP_ENABLED, false);
    settings.put(PATH_DATA, pathData);
    settings.put(PATH_WORK, pathWork);
    settings.put(PATH_LOGS, pathLogs);
    settings.put(TRANSPORT_TCP_PORT, transportTcpPort);
    settings.put(DISCOVERY_ZEN_PING_MULTICAST_ENABLED, false);

    int i = 0;
    for (String unicastHost : unicastHosts.split(",")) {
      settings.put(PATH_UNICAST_HOSTS + "." + i, unicastHost.trim());
      i++;
    }

    return settings;
  }

  @PreDestroy
  void kill() {
    // stop and close node
    if (!getNode().isClosed()) {
      getNode().close();
    }
  }

  public Node getNode() {
    return node;
  }

  @Produces
  public Client getClient() {
    return node.client();
  }
}
```

I then reacted the the construction via a CDI Event and pushed the JDBC River settings via the Java API but ended up dumping the JDBC river all together because it would bypass all the features JavaEE and Application Servers provides. (E.g. using a datasource defined by the application server)

Edit: https://github.com/dadoonet/elasticsearch-beyonder might be useful.

ps: Better answers still welcome.